# File Handling (binary File with .dat extension) in Java returning unknown compile time errror

Tags: java, bluej

```
void abIn()throws IOException
{

    FileOutputStream fos=new FileInputStream("abc.dat");
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataInputStream(fos);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter PC, Price Quantity  "+(i+1));
        pc=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        up=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        q=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        dos.writeInt(pc);
        dos.writeDouble(up);
        dos.writeInt(q);
    }
    dos.close();
    fos.close();
}
void abOut()throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("ABC.DAT");
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(fin);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Product Code");
    int x=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    boolean EOF =false;
    while(!EOF)
    {
        try
        {
            int pcx =din.readInt(pc);
            int upx=din.readDouble(up);
            int qx=din.readInt(q);
            if(pcx==x)
            {
                System.out.println(pcx+" "+upx+" "+q);
            }
        }
        catch(EOFException e)
        {}
    }
    din.close();
    fin.close();
}
public static void main()throws IOException
{
    f1 ob=new f1();
    ob.abIn();
    ob.abOut();
}
```

Unknown Compile Time Error returning. 
I tried top create a dat File with product code , product price and quantity (in Units) in Java and then Search with product code and get the other details as above input.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Exactly what is the error (copy and paste, please).

Comment: It would have helped to have the entire code. I tried to compile and it failed because of the lack of the outer class keyword.

Comment: Actually I got the fact that I had to use FileWriter instead of FileOutputStream but then comes the problem how will I display using File reader command that .

Comment: And the fact is The outer class is class abc an a header file on top of it I.e. import java.io.*;

Answer (score 1):

There are five compile errors, and they are not “unknown” at all.

```
f1.java:11: error: incompatible types: FileInputStream cannot be converted to FileOutputStream
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileInputStream("abc.dat");
                         ^
f1.java:12: error: incompatible types: FileOutputStream cannot be converted to InputStream
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataInputStream(fos);
                                               ^
f1.java:39: error: method readInt in class DataInputStream cannot be applied to given types;
            int pcx =din.readInt(pc);
                        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
f1.java:40: error: method readDouble in class DataInputStream cannot be applied to given types;
            int upx=din.readDouble(up);
                       ^
  required: no arguments
  found: double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
f1.java:41: error: method readInt in class DataInputStream cannot be applied to given types;
            int qx=din.readInt(q);
                      ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Starting with the first two:

If you want to create a FileOutputStream, create a FileOutputStream.  The same goes for DataOutputStream.  You cannot create an object designed to read a file and then tell it to write to a file.  That is not what it does.

So, you need to change these:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileInputStream("abc.dat");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataInputStream(fos);
```

to these:

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("abc.dat");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
```

The remaining errors are pretty clear.  The DataInputStream methods [readInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29) and [readDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readDouble%28%29) do not take any arguments.

If you want to get some water from a faucet, you would not expect to *provide your own water* just to get some water.  Similarly, you should not *provide an integer value* when you want to read an integer value;  the whole point of calling `readInt` is that you don’t have an integer value and you want the DataInputStream to provide you with one.

So you should not pass *your own value* to a read method.  You should pass zero arguments (that is, call the method with empty parentheses).

Furthermore, in Java, a method is uniquely identified by both its name and its arguments, so you must pass exactly the same arguments as that method declares.  `readInt` and `readDouble` are declared to take zero arguments, so you must pass zero arguments.

Therefore, you should change these three lines:

```
int pcx =din.readInt(pc);
int upx=din.readDouble(up);
int qx=din.readInt(q);
```

to this:

```
int pcx =din.readInt();
int upx=din.readDouble();
int qx=din.readInt();
```

Finally, you should not ignore `EOFException`.  That exception means there is no more data to read, so why would you want to keep trying to read data?

The correct thing to do is stop reading data:

```
catch (EOFException e)
{
    break;
}
```

Since your `EOF` variable is never used, you can actually rewrite the loop as:

```
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        int pcx = din.readInt();
        int upx = din.readDouble();
        int qx = din.readInt();
        if (pcx == x)
        {
            System.out.println(pcx+" "+upx+" "+q);
        }
    }
}
catch(EOFException e)
{
    System.out.println("No more data.");
}
```

The loop will exit when the exception is encountered.